# Selenium dynamic scraping and put in a database

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following [web page](http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/f8c676de-c871-424f-9a65-77059d07910a) (I actually have more of these types of uris butt for the sake of simplicity I am just posting one here). So, since the page is dynamic, the very first thing I have to do is open all the "plus signs" for that specific skill category indicated by the uris (I previously tried to open all the + signs but it ended in a timeout error). So here is **the question**. I am trying to do this as follows where, I believe the part that I am doing wrong is `expand_buttons = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='classification_item cont_change_right hierarchy_active']]//span[@class='api_hierarchy has-child-link']")))` :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
import time


from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#driver.get("https://esco.ec.europa.eu/en/classification/skill_main")

driver.get("http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/f8c676de-c871-424f-9a65-77059d07910a")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Define a function to click all expandable "+" buttons
def click_expand_buttons():
    while True:
        try:
            # Find all expandable "+" buttons
            expand_buttons = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='classification_item cont_change_right hierarchy_active']]//span[@class='api_hierarchy has-child-link']")))
            #expand_buttons = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            #    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".api_hierarchy.has-child-link"))
            #)

            # If no expandable buttons are found, we are done
            if not expand_buttons:
                break

            # Click each expandable "+" button
            for button in expand_buttons:
                try:
                    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
                    # Wait for the dynamic content to load
                    #time.sleep(1)
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                    # If the element is stale, we find the elements again
                    break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue

# Call the function to start clicking "+" buttons
click_expand_buttons()

# After expanding all sections, parse the page source with BeautifulSoup or extract data directly using Selenium
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

# Example of data extraction: Find all skills (this needs to be adapted based on actual page structure)
skills = []
for skill_element in soup.find_all("div", class_="skill-class"):  # Adjust selector as needed
    skill_name = skill_element.find("h2", class_="skill-name").text  # Adjust based on actual HTML structure
    skill_description = skill_element.find("p", class_="skill-description").text  # Adjust as needed
    skills.append({"name": skill_name, "description": skill_description})

# Convert the data to JSON and save it
with open("/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/escodata/expanded_esco_skills_page.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    json.dump(skills, json_file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. Someone may know how to solve one problem but not the other.

Comment: I see, I will edit by saying that even reply to one question only is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: But you need to accept the correct answer. If you have two correct answers to different questions, which will be accepted?

Comment: Please split this into two different questions.

Comment: Ok I am doing it. Thanks